# extraer datos de excel con pandas y openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, openpyxl

Estoy necesitando extraer datos de excel que tiene celdas formuladas y no me trae el resultado de las formulas, usando openpyxl me traae la formula y con pandas me trae ceros. Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de extraer el resultado de la formula con estas libreria o con otra.

Comment: Agrega el código (no capturas) para que te podamos ayudar.